# Консольное окно на весь экран - С++

Tags: c++, консоль

Здравстуйте! В С++ есть возможность открыть консольное окно на весь экран? Если есть, то как это сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте F11 .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4053554/5045688

Comment: Программно? Или "руками"?

Comment: @Harry, программно

Answer (score 0):

> Просто правой кнопкой мыши по верхушке -> свойства -> Изменить размер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы окно автоматически становилось полноэкранным. Это нужно для того, чтобы на лругих компах тоже автоматом открывалось полнэкранным